# best way to do Spring + Jersey user based API callss / transactions?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, jersey

What would the best way to handle the following scenario:

Suppose I have a DB with user info:

userid,name,age,email

and I have a REST api that can change it:

```
@POST
public void EditUserInfo( some arguments)
{
 //stuff
}
```

what would the best way to handle allowing the user to change only HIS info (i.e "update where userid = X")

should the userID be saved in a cookie and then extracted in the argument via a @Cookie?

or is there a simpiler way to handle this (or rather a more secure way?)

Comment: AOP and Security from Spring. That's it. Here's an old tutorial, but a good one for you to understand the basics. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077666/web-app-frameworks/implement-crosscutting-concerns-using-spring-2-0-aop.html

Comment: The easiest step is to plug Jersey, as jersey claseess are going to be annotated as spring beans anyway.